# Detect Red5 Broadcaster disconnection by network failure

Tags: red5

How can i detect that a broadcaster has a network failure and disconnected from Red5 server? `streamBroadcastClose` method doesnt help me. I looked at the red5 reference but couldnt find any event that detects the broadcaster disconnection.

Answer (score 0):

If there's a network disconnect, you're more likely to get a socket or write exception; there is no Flash NetConnection event specific to this type of failure that I know of.